# What's causing this error when using react-bootstrap's OverlayTrigger and Popover components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overlay, react-bootstrap, popover

I've copied and modified a react-bootstrap Popover from the examples provided [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#popovers), but it's not yet working properly. The button renders correctly, but when I click it to display the popover, I get an error saying "Element type is invalid: expected a string [...] or a class/function [...] but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component [...]".

Can anyone see what's causing this issue?

```js
import {Button, OverlayTrigger, Popover} from "react-bootstrap";
// ...
renderColumnOptionsButton() {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      trigger="click"
      placement="left"
      overlay={
        <Popover>
          <Popover.Header as="h3">
            Choose which columns to display:
          </Popover.Header>
          <Popover.Body>
            options will go here
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      }
    >
      <Button variant="secondary">Column Options</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
}
// ...
render() {
  // ...
    {this.props.allowColumnSelection &&
      {this.renderColumnOptionsButton()}
    }
  // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

I removed the Popover element from the `overlay` prop and replaced it with `<text>hello</text>`, and the overlay worked just fine. This means the issue is definitely coming from handing the Popover element to the OverlayTrigger.

I realized that the Popover requires an id prop, but when I provide one the tag gets underlined by WebStorm and tells me `Type JSX.element is not assignable to type PropTypes.Requireable[...]`.

I tried removing the Popover and placing it in a const, both with `const popover = (...)` and `const popover = () => (...)`, along with `<OverlayTrigger ... overlay={popover}>` and neither of those work either, but they don't give that WebStorm tooltip on the `id` prop anymore. I still have it set up with the latter form, and currently the line `overlay={popover}` is underlined and WebStorm again tells me `Type function is not assignable to type PropTypes.Requireable[...]`.

I'm doing it just like in the examples, but the `overlay` prop of `OverlayTrigger` seems to not like anything I give to it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:**

I figured out the issue! I'm actually using react-bootstrap v4 and instead of `<Popover.Header>` and `<Popover.Body>`, it uses `<Popover.Title>` and `<Popover.Content>`. Swapping those out fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is your `this.props.allowColumnSelection` its not true therefore won't render the component

Comment: @dippas I almost left that out to avoid any confusion, but no, unfortunately that's not the cause. The Button itself renders perfectly fine, and that's within the `renderColumnOptionsButton()` function, so it shouldn't have to do with the conditional rendering.